# How does わかってもらえればいい work

Tags: grammar

The following is the conclusion of a dialogue between the concierge and a resident. 
The concierge falsely accused the resident to be putting his bike in front of the stairs, which is not allowed. 
The misunderstanding is finally resolved and the concierge apologizes to the resident.

> Concierge: そうですね。申し訳ない。気を悪くしないでください。
>   Resident: いえ、わかって**もらえれば**いいんです。

My translation:

> Concierge: So that's how it is. I'm sorry. Please don't take this as an offense.
>   Resident: No problem, when I can receive the favor of understanding it, it is okay.

As apparent from my translation, I analysed もらえれば as a combination of the potential form and the conditional form. If it was solely conditional form, I'd expect もらえば.

I therefore tried to translate both the potential and the conditional form. It sounds a bit iffy though, that's why I wanted to ask whether that's correct and how you would translate it in a more elegant way.

Comment: My translation.  No worries.It should be alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もらう which follows a verb in -て form usually means "to get somebody to do something". "えれば" is just a -ば form ending of the -ru-verbs (potential もらえる in your case I believe), so that's pretty usual I think. So I would translate the whole sentence as:
"No problem, as long as I can get you to understand, it's fine.", meaning that the resident is glad they could get concierge to understand the situation and the incident is now over.

[Please look at this page.](http://www.manythings.org/ejs/understand.html) Specifically, at the "I don't think I can get you to understand how difficult that is." sentence. The Japanese translation is:

> 「その難しさを君に**わかってもらえる**とは思えない。」

Here you can see that わかってもらえる is "get to understand", literally "be able to receive understanding", remembering that there is usually an implicit "you" in the sentence when addressing others in Japanese. Also, appropriately mentioned in comments, you don't say もらう to yourself. Now we have literal "If you are able to receive understanding, good".

Or, in proper English:

"No problem, if I can get you to understand, it's fine."

Comment: the dictionary form isn't もらえる　but もらう. The potential form is もらえるhttp://jisho.org/search/morau
Also, as can be seen on jisho, もらう has a "receive" semantics, so "get somebody to do smthg." can't be expressed with it I think.

Comment: @Narktor Yes, the dictionary form is of course もらう, and もらえる is a potential form. So do you think it could mean something like the ability to understand? I initially treated this as passive even though it's clearly a potential form. So my suggestion including this fix would be: "No problem, it's good [if/when] I can get you to understand.". I also believe this is still "get to understand" meaning, just because we have a complex "わかってもらう" form here with -て, not just "わかる" and もらう on their own.

Comment: Oh I overlooked that concerning もらう in your answer. 
Hm, well i could also imagine that he is okay with the concierges complaint as long as he understands the motives behind it. That's why I hesitate to let わかる refer to the concierge。

Comment: @Narktor You can't refer わかる to the resident now, can you? You don't say もらう to youself. This is a very common phrase, it means "as long as I can get you to understand, it's fine".

Comment: @KimitsuDesu So basically, my answer is correct, right? I too thought that I've heard this one before a couple of times.

Comment: @Narktor http://www.manythings.org/ejs/understand.html
Check this link. It has the following example: 
その難しさを君にわかってもらえるとは思えない。
Which is translated: "I don't think I can get you to understand how difficult that is. "
So it pretty much proves I was right. Could you please accept my answer?

Comment: @Narktor I've updated my answer with all the findings and fixes.